# TypeError: this.transferPropsTo is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

This is the react component I'm trying to render

```
    var APP = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div><BButton className="btn-primary">I <BHeart/> React</BButton>
                <BButton className="btn-succes">I <BHeart/> React</BButton>
                <BButton className="btn-danger">I <BHeart/> React</BButton>
            </div>
        )
    }

});

var BButton = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return this.transferPropsTo(
            <a className="btn">{this.props.children}</a>
        )
    }

});

var BHeart = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
        )
    }
});

});
```

But in  the console,

> TypeError: this.transferPropsTo is not a function

comes up. I have googled by couldn't find an answer so far.

Comment: The Reactjs version is 15.6.1.

Comment: In react-bootstrap, `transferPropsTo` is [deprecated](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/188). I suppose you are using bootstrap?

Comment: @PeterMader Yeah I'm using bootstrap.

Comment: @kokilayaa Did u try binding the function with this ?

Comment: @rohankangale Yeah but not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can not render a undefined function. You should write:

***App.js***

```
var APP = React.createClass({
render () {
    return (
        <div>

            <BButton bla = "something"  className="btn-primary">I <BHeart/> React</BButton>
            <BButton className="btn-succes">I <BHeart/> React</BButton>
            <BButton className="btn-danger">I <BHeart/> React</BButton>
        </div>
    );
 }

});

var BButton = React.createClass({

render: () {
    //bla is props. 
    {bla}=this.props;
    //If exist pros bla then render <a></a>, if not then null 
    return(
        {bla ? <a className="btn">{this.props.bla}</a> : null}
    )
}

 });

 var BHeart = React.createClass({
render () {
    return (
        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
           )
     }
  });

});
```

Comment: But this doesn't transfer the properties to the new element.

Comment: @PeterMader: i fixed my answer. The old answer is only explain , why he got this error :D

Answer (score 0):

`transferPropsTo` is now [deprecated](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/188). But you can achieve the same using the ES2015 and JSX spread operator (`...`):

```
var BButton = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var { children, ...other } = this.props; // use destructuring and the spread operator to read the properties
    // 'children' contains 'this.props.children', 'other' contains all properties except 'children'
    return ( // use the JSX spread operator the set all properties
      <a {...other} className="btn btn-primary">{this.props.children}</a>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to override the CSS properties here.